# Having issues shutting down

Tags: shutdown

I just installed Ubuntu, and am a very new user. I'm not quite sure the proper way to shut it down, and everything I try when I boot back up it says it's finishing the install, and then I lose everything I've done.

Comment: So you have completed the installation including the restart that it says to do? Or are you having the problem at that stage?

Comment: I've done the reboot (I have a disc) and it starts up totally fine. But no matter what I do (suspend, log off, shut down) when I go to start it back up it comes up with the "completing installation" screen, and then everything is back to the way it started.

Comment: So have you installed the Ubuntu ISO on the disk? Or have you got the disk from somewhere else?

Comment: (Sorry hit enter too quick) I got the disc from elsewhere

Comment: Did you get the disk from an official source, such as Canonical? Because it sounds very much like the installation disk is either corrupted or has been tampered with.

Comment: Damn. I was worried about that.

Comment: I would advise that you create a bootable USB or disk from a downloadable ISO, and then boot from that and install.

Comment: It actually does the publisher is Canonical. Do you think it could still be corrupted?

Comment: It appears to be corrupted, but it could be a problem with the actual computer, the only real way to tell would be to install Ubuntu with a bootable USB and see if the problem still occurs.